# Is DocuSign Payment possible through DocuSign SOAP API?

Tags: docusignapi

We're currently have our application integrated to DocuSign through the DocuSign SOAP API.  We want to use DocuSign Payment with Stripe.  Trying to determine if the DocuSign SOAP API will work in creating the payment tab or will we need to switch to using DocuSign REST API.

The effort of rewriting our integration to use DocuSign REST API is a bigger task so looking to see if the SOAP API will work with DocuSign Payment since I couldn't find any example.

Answer (score 0):

For many use cases, a template can hold the fields (tags) needed for payments. So you could create a template that includes payments using the DocuSign web tool, then create an envelope via SOAP that uses the template.

If you want to include the specific payment tag via SOAP, that might be problematic since the tag is not in the [WSDL](https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?WSDL). There is no plan to update the WSDL.

If you can create the SOAP message manually, you could try to add the payment tag. See workflow example 14. Here is the [Java version.](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/examples/EG014ControllerCollectPayment.java#L270)

Comment: We cannot use templates because our document are generated dynamically with the tags within them.  Since the payment detail elements are not within the WSDL, you can't simply add them to the SOAP message since DocuSign SOAP service will rejected the message since it validates the element and namespace.

Comment: Seem like the only way for us to use the DocuSign Payment is to swap out and utilize the DocuSign REST API?